# Django Apps aren't loaded yet Celery Tasks

Tags: python, django, celery

What is giving the error below? I'm unsure if this is a problem with an app I have installed or one of mine. The exception below is generated only when running Celery i.e. `celery -A demo.apps.wall.tasks worker` , runserver does not generate any errors. Which app ios the issue?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/Documents/workspace/demo-api/env/bin/celery", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/Users/user/Documents/workspace/demo-api/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/__main__.py", line 30, in main
    main()
  File "/Users/user/Documents/workspace/demo-api/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 81, in main
    cmd.execute_from_commandline(argv)
  File "/Users/user/Documents/workspace/demo-api/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 770, in execute_from_commandline
    super(CeleryCommand, self).execute_from_commandline(argv)))
  File "/Users/user/Documents/workspace/demo-api/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/bin/base.py", line 309, in execute_from_commandline
    argv = self.setup_app_from_commandline(argv)
  File "/Users/user/Documents/workspace/demo-api/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/bin/base.py", line 469, in setup_app_from_commandline
    self.app = self.find_app(app)
  File "/Users/user/Documents/workspace/demo-api/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/bin/base.py", line 489, in find_app
    return find_app(app, symbol_by_name=self.symbol_by_name)
  File "/Users/user/Documents/workspace/demo-api/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/app/utils.py", line 238, in find_app
    sym = imp(app)
  File "/Users/user/Documents/workspace/demo-api/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/utils/imports.py", line 101, in import_from_cwd
    return imp(module, package=package)
  File "/Users/user/Documents/workspace/demo-api/env/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 662, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/user/Documents/workspace/demo-api/demo/apps/Walls/tasks.py", line 14, in <module>
    from demo.apps.Walls.redis_models import WallSchedule, WallBroadcast, UserWalls
  File "/Users/user/Documents/workspace/demo-api/demo/apps/Walls/redis_models.py", line 12, in <module>
    from demo.apps.memberships.models import Membership
  File "/Users/user/Documents/workspace/demo-api/demo/apps/memberships/models.py", line 4, in <module>
    from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
  File "/Users/user/Documents/workspace/demo-api/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/contenttypes/models.py", line 161, in <module>
    class ContentType(models.Model):
  File "/Users/user/Documents/workspace/demo-api/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 94, in __new__
    app_config = apps.get_containing_app_config(module)
  File "/Users/user/Documents/workspace/demo-api/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 239, in get_containing_app_config
    self.check_apps_ready()
  File "/Users/user/Documents/workspace/demo-api/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 124, in check_apps_ready
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
```

Running `manage.py check` is ok.

Comment: What does your celery file look like - did you set the Django settings inside? This isn't an issue with Django itself (which is why manage.py check is fine).

Comment: @JensAstrup I'll post the Celery Task File one second : thanks

Comment: Which version of Django are you using? Did you upgrade from a previous version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok - after posting your celery app files I compared to what I have and tried running. *Think* I found your issue - it looks like you're calling tasks.py in `celery -A demo.apps.wall.tasks`.

If your wall module contains celery.py, and tasks.py - you should call `celery -A demo.apps.wall`.

Here's the directory structure I have, and the celery command I run:

```
django_project
- an_app
- celery_tasks
   - init.py
   - celery_app.py (celery.py in your case)
   - tasks.py
```

The command I run: `celery worker -A celery_tasks` from the django_project directory.

Comment: When I call  `celery -A demo.apps.celery worker` I get an import error. `ImportError: No module named 'memberships'`, but celery.py does not import memberships, which is strange. This was all working until I updated Django. I think something has not registered correctly.

Comment: What's the full traceback you get? It should show where you're trying to import/where it's going wrong.

Answer (score 4):

ContentType provide you the names of apps that you installed, so if you import them before the model run that will cause this error,

```
try:
   from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
except:
   pass
```

- also apps have the same issu

```
try:
   from django.apps import apps
except:
   pass
```

- alternatively you cam import it inside the function where you use it instead of importing it in the top of you file

```
    def MyFunction(self):
        from django.contrib.auth.models import Permission
        from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
        from django import apps

        ....
```

- other solution add this top of ur file, to tell Django where are the settings

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'MyProject.settings')

import django
django.setup()
```

Comment: Please be more elaborate, provide an [explanation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

The main reason for the exception `AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't load` is because if you try to import any files in your app, before initializing your celery app.

Dont try to importing tasks.py in celery.py or pass task.py functions like this
`app.autodiscover_tasks(task1)`

best practice is to use `@shared_task` in your tasks.py

and also leave `app.autodiscover_tasks()` empty.
Here's [a link to a sample git](https://github.com/Reymond190/django-celery-myex.git)

also if you cant import your models into your tasks.py,
1. check that your celery.py is clear without any app file imports.
2. dont pass arguments to autodiscover_tasks() (unnecessary aruguments) autodiscover_tasks() (automatically searches for `@shared_tasks`)

Answer (score 1):

A possible scenario is you importing models on the top of the file. Move those imports to the method/func where you are using them.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, the tasks in tasks.py does not loaded if the tasks.py is futher deep folders. My case, I have to load them in appConfig ready method like below:

```
import importlib

from django.apps import AppConfig
from django.conf import settings


class ClientConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'apps.client'

    def ready(self):
        super(ClientConfig, self).ready()
        importlib.import_module(f"{self.name}.api.v1.foldera.tasks")
```